# Using Django on Laravel?

Tags: php, python, django, laravel, api

I recently started on a project using Laravel and I'm curious to know that if I can consume Django web services on Laravel.

I tried searching google but all that came up were comparisons on it. I want to know if there are any struggles or issues when integrating a python api for php.

(ps. I'm clueless to a lot of these stuffs so am sorry if somethings aren't clear to me)

Comment: Web services should (at least in theory) be platform agnostic. Why should it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to with your Django program from within Laravel there are 2 possible ways of doing this:

1. Guzzle, PHP HTTP client - This will allow you to get and posts from within PHP: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/
2. The Symfony Process Component - which allows you to execute python code in from within PHP and get the anything that is returned: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Will check them out

Comment: Your more than welcome! I happened to be looking into the same problem the other day.